# Tell Cmake where to find libraries that I have built from source

Tags: linux, cmake, point-cloud-library

I want to build in Ubuntu the *PCl 1.7* library from source, so I have downloaded and built from source some of its dependencies: *VTK 5.8*, *Boost 1.51.0* and *FLANN 1.7.1*.

I have built them in a custom directory. All of them are stored under the directory */home/c/pkg*. The structure in that dir is:

For Boost:

- boost-1.51.0

  - build: I told the *bjam* tool to use this dir for installation. Here's the *boost/bin.v2* folder.
  - include: header files.
  - lib: *.a* and *.so* objects.

For VTK:

- vtk-5.8.0

  - build: where *CMake* was executed.
  - include: header files.
  - lib: shared objects.

For FLANN:

- flann-1.7.1

  - build: *CMake* was executed here.
  - include: header files.
  - lib: shared objects.
  - share: docs.

Other dependencies like *OpenNI* or *OpenSceneGraph* have been built from source and installed system wide (to the /usr/...) dir.

I have tested the installation with a little program and I can compile and link to them. So, everything works fine :)

**NOTE BEFORE CONTINUINING:** I have previous versions of those libraries, like *boost-1.4* or *pcl-1.6* installed system-wide with the Synaptics tool. I want to keep them, as I'm only testing the newer versions. That's why I have built the libraries in that custom location.

The problem is that when I want to compile *PCL 1.7*, by default, *CMake* only recognizes the system-wide installed libraries. So, how can I tell *CMake* to use the newer libraries I have built from source?.

Thanks for your time!.

Comment: Not sure about FLANN, but for VTK and Boost you can set VTK_DIR and BOOST_ROOT as CMake variables, before calling find_package. Did you try that one already?

Comment: I tried to tell Cmake the path to Boost and VTK with `SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} <path>`, but it didn't work. I'll try what you said and report back.

Comment: Alternatively, for VTK you can pass a "hint" to find_package: find_package( VTK REQUIRED HINTS ${Your_VtkDIR} )

Comment: Thanks!. Once I get home I'll try both!.

Comment: Hello. In the end I dind't use that approach. I installed `ccmake` and configured the project from there. In the `advanced view` mode I was able to tell where to find all the libraries needed. Nonetheless, I'll try your suggestion, @Andre. If it works, I'll ask you to post it as an answer so I can vote it up :)